# Can modern radios/ham sets/digital walkie talkies be exploited?

Tags: exploit

Given the fact that modern radios/walkie talkies/ham sets have CPUs on them...would it be possible to exploit them? I am thinking in the following scenario:

-There is a vulnerability in the function that processes the analog radio signals and thus an attacker can exploit it and achieve RCE (Maybe an stack buffer overflow?).

Or given some architecture design/electronical detail is this impossible?

Comment: Do you have any example of them? I believe they have a DSP inside, not a CPU.

Comment: My bad...I don't know that much about electronics. I thought it was a CPU! Editing to reflect that.

Comment: A DSP does not run code... it's just a Digital Signal Processor.

Comment: @ThoriumBR https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/595631/are-there-any-digital-walkie-talkies-or-radios-with-cpus-on-them?noredirect=1#comment1563519_595631 well the guys over at electrical engineering answered the question whether they have cpus or not :P

Comment: @ThoriumBR a) a DSP  runs code and can be exploited; it's been done more than once. b) any modern radio has a CPU. c) a DSP in that role can very much be considered a CPU, if it's not  a peripheral to another processor (which then would be called a CPU).

Comment: (by the way, we have enough questions of the kind "can this XYZ be exploited?" and the answer is always the same: depends, and you haven't even started to define what an exploit would be or defined the capabilities of the exploiter)

Comment: Vulnerability? Stack buffer overflow. Exploit? RCE. Does it make sense? I don't know. I am asking. That's why I'm here. I am missing something? Please tell me.

Comment: @4d4143 I think you might be missing a bit of having thought about what makes a device do what it does (namely, software running on microcontrollers, DSPs and similar devices with a CPU core). Then your question would have answered itself :) That's not really a big thing. The thing is, there's no end to the kind of question that is "could this vaguesly defined class of devices have an RCE vulnerability", and the answer is *always* going to be yes, as long as there's a state machine of any kind interacting with the outer world, and as long as humans and machines make errors.

Comment: Oh. I mean...I never saw it mentioned or came across a paper regarding that so that's why I asked. Everything I've seen regarding exploits is on IOT or Desktops/laptops/servers/smartphones and through networking. Haven't seen ham sets/walkie talkies and through radio signals.

Comment: well, you must have searched things that are focused on things that aren't embedded. This might simply be a case of too much material - the amount of good and not-so-good articles on the devices that security researchers without hardware background are familiar with is simply higher than articles about embedded devices, simply because you simply need a bit of additional knowledge besides software security.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROppOLeB6_I you want to watch this from the beginning to roughly the middle just to get a feeling for what things look like in such systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your example vulnerabilities is that they are from the perspective of a multi-function computer with software and an OS.

Please don't take the answer from [your post on Electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/595631/are-there-any-digital-walkie-talkies-or-radios-with-cpus-on-them?noredirect=1#comment1563519_595631) and jump ahead in your logic. Your use of "CPU" is specific. "Microcontrollers" are different from CPUs. Don't jump ahead to think that because there are microcontrollers in a device that the breadth and scope of the vulnerabilities of a *computer* apply.

Can ***any firmware*** have vulnerabilities and be exploited? Absolutely. Radios are not special. Printers, cameras, [sex toys](https://www.wired.co.uk/article/sex-toy-bluetooth-hacks-security-fix), etc. they all have microcontrollers and all have firmware, and they all have weaknesses.

Comment: I agree. But  that being said, many modern handsets have what they call "codeplugs", Over-the-air updates, run multi-tasking OSes with or without support of an MMU, have fancy GUI including graphics libraries, data parsing, text and binary protocol handling, multiple connected processors with their own firmware... I'd argue that one of these handsets' computer architecture and security "scope" is closer to a 2009 smartphone than to that of a toaster.

Comment: You haven't seen my toys, then ;)

Comment: " The researchers in Israel have developed malware that exploits this vulnerability by generating radio signals that can transmit modulated data that is then received and decoded by the FM radio receiver built into mobile phones" This is crazy!! Wow, got some material for my degree thesis. Thanks @schroeder!

Comment: @4d4143 if this is your degree, then you should probably first familiarize yourself with the background and hardware architectures!

Comment: Yes, after finishing the first semester and getting into computer architecture, I will get more info and knowledge :D